# UITableView crash despite cellForRowAtIndexPath returning valid cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm having some issues with a crash occurring when I change view controllers - Basically I have a VC that takes data from the user for a search - it then brings up a new VC with search results, displayed in a UITableView (not using a `UITableViewController`, just a TableView inside a regular `UIViewController`)

**Crash Log:**

> > 2016-08-29 20:48:03.950 MyApp[2596:60877] *** Assertion failure in -[SearchResultsTable _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:7971
> >
> > 2016-08-29 20:48:03.961 MyApp[2596:60877]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 1128}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}>)'
> >     *** First throw call stack:

I've read that this issue is caused by not returning a cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, however i'm positive that my implementation will return a cell successfully. (I tested the code of the function somewhere else, and `cell` does in fact have a value, and is not nil.)

**Code:**

`@property searchResultCell * cell;`

```
-(UITableViewCell*)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     _cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (_cell == nil)
    {
        _cell = [[searchResultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    [[_cell txtDate] setText:@"test"];
    return _cell;
}
```

Having placed some breakpoints down, it appears that this section of code is never even executed, despite the `UITableView` class, delegate and dataSource being set correctly.

viewDidLoad for the Search Results VC (`[self SpecifiedSerial]` is set previously before the segue happens. It is an `NSString*`):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

_SearchResultsTableDelegate = [[searchResultsTable alloc] init:[self specifiedSerial]];

[[self SearchResultsTable] setDelegate:_SearchResultsTableDelegate];
[[self SearchResultsTable] setDataSource:_SearchResultsTableDelegate];
}
```

Declarations:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *SearchResultsTable;
@property searchResultsTable * SearchResultsTableDelegate;
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction here, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show where and when you call it?

Comment: Try this  UITableViewCell *_cell = [yourTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];   if (_cell == nil)
    {
    _cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];}

Comment: Show more code, why is the delegate not setting itself as the table delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Instead of:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     _cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**Edit:**

Your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` seems to be incorrect.

Try this code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[self searchedTrainSightings] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (_cell == nil)
    {
        _cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    [[_cell textLabel] setText:@"test"];
    return _cell;
}
```

Comment: Didn't fix the issue sadly, however I got a warning after I changed it - apparently the method is never used.

Comment: `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` implemented?

Comment: I have implemented those, however like previously I was missing the `tableView:`. When I add this, it throws an error `Duplicate declaration of method`. Would a link to Github be fine to post?

Comment: Yeah! That will be more helpful.

Comment: [Github link](https://github.com/Swemoph/RailSpotter) files that we are working with here are `SearchResultsVC.h`, `SearchResultsVC.m`, `TrainSearchResultsTable.m` and `TrainSearchResultsTable.h`. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't contain `.xcodeProj` file? Check edited code.

Comment: I got it to work with the code you posted above plus a little bit of playing. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Welcome, I was surprised to see those delegates and datasource methods. 
Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

probably the reason is you are returning nil from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and failing to dequeue a reusable cell.

use code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    searchResultCell *cell; 
    cell = (searchResultCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[searchResultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    [[_cell txtDate] setText:@"test"];
    return cell;
}
```

And just configure your cell selecting your custom cell giving `cell` identifier using storyboard *see image*.
[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt the delegate method which you are using. I have seen this version of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (_cell == nil)
    {
        _cell = [[searchResultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    [[_cell txtDate] setText:@"test"];
    return _cell;
}
```